# Some calculations before adding/updating a record in MVC Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a question about MVC. I am practicing it recently.

I have created a sample application. Assume that this is a cash register.

In the cash register, I want to calculate some values before I insert the record or before I update the record.

- The user clicks on "Create New" on a table X.
- The "Create" action is invoked.
- Before the record is created, I want to call a function (say "CheckCashRegister") which will automatically perform the following:

  - if the user has created 5 records in another table (say Y), we will insert a record into table Z.
  - if the user has created 10 records in table Y, we will update a record in table Z.

My question is two-fold:

1. I want to implement these in Model. And I don't want to use repositories. This may not be the best approach, but I am inexperienced. What are your suggestions?
2. After I implement these in Model, how will I invoke it?

Thanks for your answers, in advance.

Comment: This question effectively asks for someone to lay out an entire architecture for your application - narrow it down to a *specific* question with a *specific* answer or it is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching through several web sites, I found that Model is the right place for doing these.